# Modifying subclass properties with superclass function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, oop, inheritance

My subclass has the same properties as my superclass.
This looks like the following

```
classdef superclass < handle
    properties
      a
      b
      c
    methods
      function sup = superclass(...)
          sup.create(...)
      end

classdef subclass < superclass
    properties
      a1
      b1
      c1
    methods
      function sub = subclass(...)
```

Now I would like the constructor of subclass to first initialise the superclass properties

```
    sub@superclass()
```

and then (this is where I am stuck) the subclass constructor to secondly initialise all the values a1, b1, c1.
Since the procedure which initialises the properties does not change between sup and sub, I would like to reuse it like this:

```
    function sub = subclass(args1, args2)
       sub@superclass(args1)
       sub.create(args2)
```

How can I reach this, without writing a new 'create' function for the subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to refactor the `create` method to return three values (instead of hard-coding the properties), then you can call it in both the superclass and the sublcass as:

```
[sup.a,sup.b,sup.c] = sup.create(...);
```

and

```
[sub.a1,sub.b1,sub.c1] = sub.create(args2);
```

where

```
classdef superclass < handle
    methods (Access = protected)
        function [x,y,z] = create(obj, args)
            x = ..; y = ...; z = ...;
        end
    end
end
```

Alternatively, you could perhaps use dynamic field names to abstract that part:

```
propname = 'a';
obj.(propname) = 0;
```

and have the `create` method receive a cell array of strings containing the property names to fill.